# Constricted phoneme /i/ in French?

Tags: phonétique

Related to this question: [Nasal /i/ in French exists?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49610/nasal-i-in-french-exists)

I noticed at times, the phoneme /i:/ in French is pronounced with more "constriction", like it happens in Swedish
(https://youtu.be/wIlOPJLhks4?t=37 at 0:37 on "latin")

Same as Juan in the related question, I also thought at first that it was due to some kind of interaction with the preceding phoneme, but I came across a sample of a native speaker doing this on the word "si" with the vowel somewhat elongated:
https://www.youtube.com/live/OWp1LZNU7k0?t=911 (at 15:11)

It's especially clear when you compare it to something like the Spanish "sí" or "si"

Here is another example given by Juan, along with his thoughts

> Here's a link to a video of a female French native speaker: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-_EZDKFv7U

> I think she realizes that same phoneme when uttering certain words such as "aujourd'hui" (0:37 in the video)--which could be some sort of a diphthong pattern where /i:/ is somehow affected by the preceding phoneme /ɥ/--and then again at 1:02 when she says "traduire" (same mechanics involved as the example above).

> I definitely hear more constriction in the realization of that /i:/. It may only occur in the phonetic diphthong pattern /ɥi/ that is phonemically realized as /ɥɪ̝ʝ/ (if that even exists, of course); I don't have any other examples at the moment, but I'll share them with you in case I come across any in the future.

Is this part of a dialectal variation? Where can I find more information about this?

I couldn't find any sources regarding this, but I'm not sure what I would even search for.

Edit: additional example: https://youtu.be/A_EkF94Zg0k?t=173 (Ici, cabinet, Tel-Aviv)

Comment: I think the long "si" of Elisa is more due to hesitation, like she's not sure what she'll say next

Answer (score 4):

There are no dialectal variations in these videos.

Elisa chose to pronounce /'si: vu.za.'ve/ but she could just as easily have said /si.vu.za.'ve/. What lengthens the *i* and I believe causes what you call a *constriction* effect is the pause before *vous*.

In the second video, a similar optional pause follows *aujourd'hui*, before *nous allons parler*. At the end of *traduire*, Elisabeth makes a pause that is not expected in regular speech. She slows down her speech to make it easier for learners to understand. This is certainly what Elisa also does in *Si vous avez*.

You are less likely to find these /i:/ in everyday speech, except for example by someone who is hesitating.

That said, an *i* used in a stressed syllable is often longer than an *i* located elsewhere.

Comment: I also hear it without any elongation or pause, like here on "cabinet" and "Tel-Aviv": https://youtu.be/A_EkF94Zg0k?t=173

Comment: @LiberaVeritas It's difficult for me to hear any specific constriction in that last sample. These *i* sound regular to my hear. Maybe should you put in parallel an *i* that doesn't exhibit the characteristic you are looking for.

Comment: @jlliangre Here is one side by side: https://youtu.be/MnhhOrtTqIc?t=137 "parti" from two different speakers (the speakers have different dialects in this video, but it doesn't affect the sample for comparison)

It's a little more subtle here than with other instances in the video, but it makes a nice side-by-side comparison

Comment: @LiberaVeritas Thanks, I have to admit that I don't perceive any fundamental difference, apart from the pitch. I'm afraid this goes beyond my level of e̶x̶p̶e̶r̶t̶i̶s̶e̶  amateurism...

Answer (score 0):

The pronunciation of i in all the examples you provide is not nasalized.

- [i]  si, aujourd'hui, traduire,
- [ĩ]  imparfait, lin, pincer, mince, (*nasalized*)

There is more constriction in the pronunciation of the i in "traduire", which means that she pronunces it very nearly as cardinal i ([voyelles cardinales](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_cardinale)); one of the reasons for that is that she places a high pitched intonation on this syllable (dui). This is not the usual way to pronounce i (most of the time there is less constriction), but in main stream French it is perfectly acceptable to fluctuate between the more usual pronunciation of i and this high pitched i. It becomes apparent that there is such variation when one considers the pronunciation of "oui" for which at one extreme there is even a new spelling that reflects better this limit pronunciation (ouais, \wɛ).  This variablity in the constriction (/wi, wɪ, we, wɛ) is not typical of the pronunciation of i in all cases: it is only true for "oui", but it shows that at times an [i] might be realized as an allophone quite near to [ɪ].

Comment: Did you mean [ɛ̃] for the the nasal vowel in imparfait, lin, pincer ? /mɛ̃s/.  Not getting into the brin-brun but it's largely realized as [ɛ̃], some [œ̃].  No nasal [i].

Comment: @livresque The transcription you mention is right today, but it is said that initially that was a nasalization of i : "Au xiii e siècle, uniquement en syllabe fermée, [i] suivi d'une consonne nasale se nasalise en [ĩ] puis s'ouvre en [ę̃] au xiv e siècle". (1/2)

Comment: @livresque (https://www.google.com/search?q=nasalisation+de+i+en+fran%C3%A7ais&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AB5stBj8wblliyRvz-ard8Rj-v2zieIH5Q%3A1690270160382&ei=0Hm_ZKbsFrCdkdUP-5iVYA&oq=nasalisation+de+i&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiEW5hc2FsaXNhdGlvbiBkZSBpKgIIADIEECMYJzIIEAAYCBgeGA1I6EFQ6gZYth1wAngBkAEAmAGjAaABywOqAQMwLjO4AQHIAQD4AQHCAgoQABhHGNYEGLAD4gMEGAAgQYgGAZAGCA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp (2/2)

Comment: It’s also quite common for _oui_ to go the opposite direction and be pronounced with a **very** constricted /i/, something like [wi͡ʝ] (as noted in the quote in the question), or even with devoicing, rendering it something like [wiç]. This is very similar to what frequently happens with /iː/ in Swedish (except for the devoicing, that doesn’t usually happen in Swedish), and it is significantly more constricted than the cardinal vowel [i].